# Book recommendations for fourier series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

I am a physics Student, i have finished both volumes of TOM M.APOSTOL calculus, but it doesn't have any chapter related to Fourier series, can you suggest me a book through which i can directly refer to Fourier series chapter with some what similar style like apostol.

Comment: To fully grasp the power of Fourier Series I'd say you need some basic complex analysis. I remark this because you wrote about Apostol's (real) calculus books

Comment: Apostol calculus has only a very basic introduction to complex spaces, i just want to understand basic of Fourier series so that i can use them in physics. So if you can suggest me a short book introducing complex analysis with fourier series then it will be nice

Comment: I don't know whether it's like Apostol or not, but Mathematical Methods for Science Students by G. Stephenson covers widely, and includes Fourier series. I used Engineering Mathematics by Spencer et.al. for my electronics degree back in the early 80s and found it excellent. I endorse Boyce and DiPrima. Mathematical Methods for Physicsts by George Arfken is another. All of these are hefty.

Answer (score 3):

The book Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems by Boyce and DiPrima explains Fourier series. I recommend checking it out. You might also take a look at Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems by Brown and Churchill. Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences by Boas is also worth a look.

The function $e^{2\pi i t}$ makes one revolution as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$. It is the very essence of periodic motion. The function$e^{2 \pi i k  t}$ completes $k$ revolutions as $t$ goes from $0$ to $1$. It is the essence of periodic motion at a higher frequency. Given a complex-valued function $f$ with period $1$ (perhaps $f(t)$ is the position of a planet at time $t$), a deep idea is to try to represent $f$ as a combination of pure frequencies:
$$
\tag{1} f(t) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} c_k e^{2 \pi i k t}.
$$
This is the idea behind Fourier series. The numbers $c_k$ are called the Fourier coefficients of the function $f$. To compute $c_j$, use Fourier's trick: multiply both sides of (1) by $e^{-2\pi i j t}$, integrate from $0$ to $1$, and observe the wonderful cancellation that occurs.

Amazingly, any reasonably nice complex-valued function $f$ with period $1$ can be represented as in (1). Ancient astronomers benefited from this fact, unknowingly, when they used epicycles to describe the motions of planets.

Comment: Might be worth adding the info that it is usually more immediately accessible to consider the Fourier series in the trig form. Also, is there an i missing from your exponent function in the summation above?

Comment: I was going through the elementary DE by boyceand diprima and i didn't found fourier series part in it,it contains almoat same part as apostol books contain, i found boas bool intresting,i think i should try it, thanks a ton

Comment: Ah, it's the book Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems by Boyce and DiPrima which includes Fourier series.

Comment: Yes i got it,10th chapter, i am looking through it, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You would have a rigorous introduction from Apostol. So I would recommend a solid book in Fourier Analysis. One that comes to mind is

*Fourier Analysis: An Introduction (Princeton Lectures in Analysis, Volume 1)*
by Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi.